# Styling the font size in a nav bar

Tags: css, sass

The font size scales up/down based on the size of the browser to fit the nav bar buttons (using `@media`).

```
.navButtonText p{
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', serif;
                 font-weight:900;
                 color: gray;
                 font-size: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    .navButtonText p{
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', serif;
                 font-weight:900;
                 color: gray;
                 font-size: 18px;
line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    .navButtonText p{
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', serif;
                 font-weight:900;
                 color: gray;
                 font-size: 16px;
line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .navButtonText p{
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', serif;
                 font-weight:900;
                 color: gray;
                 font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    .navButtonText p{
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', serif;
                 font-weight:900;
                 color: gray;
                 font-size: 12px;
line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
}
```

As you can see, it is quite a bit of styling for one thing. I was wondering if there was a way I could clean up this code, so I wouldn't need to have it in these many lines.

I have SASS and Compass which I am willing to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove all the duplicate lines in the `@media queries` and provide only the **changes** in these tags. This is beacause in CSS, the CSS classes that are interpreted by the browser down-most on your page, are the ones prevailing in your final design. All previous defined CSS rules apply unless overwritten. In your case this means that only the `font-size` changes and should be redefined:

```
.navButtonText p {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: gray;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    .navButtonText p {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    .navButtonText p {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .navButtonText p {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    .navButtonText p {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

FYI: there is away to prevent this from happening, using the [!important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) tag.

Comment: You have an extra closing bracket for `.navButtonText p` css

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out, I copied his CSS though, it's also wrong in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You could also go for a scss or less solution (the syntax would be identical for both preprocessors in this case), which imo gives you even cleaner code the what @JohannesB suggested. The resulting (compiled) css would be the same though.

```
.navButtonText p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 6px;

  @media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

Comment: You missed the `max-width:450px` and `font-size:14px`, other than that, good answer.

Comment: sorry about the confusion guys, I didn't know CodeReview was a thing.

Comment: @Jonathan, on SO it is not considered good practice to focus on the person instead of on the content, please read the name-calling section in the [be nice-policy](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).